# jQuery Sliders with adding, subtracting, dividing etc with numeric values

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello all at StackOverflow..

Reasonably new to this site, but I have had nothing but good and great feedback! So firstly would thankyou to you all!

What I would like to do would do is something similar to wonga
https://www.wonga.com/

But with the value's working together, I would like a group of around 5 sliders with the first one being the 'total' amount, then the rest showing totals as they slid along. Then at the bottom showing the total value left over and then with an input field with what ever they could put in.

Ideally - what is going to go on is the average person will have 3000

Then they will minus the total bills, rent, food, nights out, transport and other.

This will then leave the total value, and then have an option for a box, in which they can enter the amount of weeks, then this number will divide the remainder value.

Basically a bill calculator using jQuery UI sliders, I have looked around, on the internet and on stackoverflow but Don't really know how to incorporate it. As well as it being styled well.

Hope you can help! Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a demo/tutorial that should help

http://www.rezb.com/jquery-loan-calculator-using-sliders/

Comment: the slider's are not appearing, just the values? I am missing something, like a relation to a js script it seems?

Comment: your asking about something I can't see